# How to import security configuration class from another module

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, multi-module

I want to develop my security config in separate module and add it as dependency in main app. so I wrote a very simple test project as parent which has 2 child modules: **security-module** and **app**

**security-module** has only one configuration class as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("h").
                password("1").
                roles("admin");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

In **app** module, I have a **SecurityConfig** class which is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        Security.class
})
public class SecurityConfig{
}
```

also the *resources* directory is as follow:

[image]

The problem is **HttpSecurity** object, configured in **Security** class, is not registered completely. Said completely cause if I add `anyRequest().pertmitAll()` in **Security** class, then all is good, but now for any request i get 403 error, even when I call resources explicity like *localhost:8080/dash.html*

I also tried extending **Security** as follow in **SecurityConfig**:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends Security{
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

but nothing changed.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: *Said completely cause if I add anyRequest().pertmitAll() in Security class, then all is good* Then your configuration is use, no need for another class `SecurityConfig `.

Comment: *but now for any request i get 403 error* You are not logged in. You have to login first.

Comment: I already explained it: *You only allow /, login and /static/, none of them is matching the URL `/dash.html`* You have to add another URL for your matcher that matches your URL `/dash.html`. BTW: The matcher for `/static/` isn't neccessary, because there is nothing.

Comment: @dur well, that's weird. i thought spring boot will try match both resources and URL. I think i misunderstood the documentation.thank you. By the way, why the `jquery` can not be imported to _index.html_ ? it is in _/static/js/_ folder. it returns 403!

Comment: Because `js` is not allowed in your Spring Security configuration. Spring Boot exposes all files under `static` folder with its folder structure mapped to the URL.

Comment: @dur but _/static/**_ means all directories in _static_ path

Comment: @dur now i understand what's happening. my mistake was when i add **/static** it is actually the _static_ directory in _resources_, but actually setting **/** in configuration refers to _static_ directory!!
I specified _/static/**_ in configuration but it only applies if i put `js` files in a _static_ directory inside _static_, like **/resources/static/static/js**
thank you for your help.